# Software or Service to Automatically Generate Custom Ordered Lists?

Tags: reporting, relational-database, custom-lists

**Disclaimer:** *I'm not a programmer, so this question is non-technical and probably very basic. I am just hoping to be pointed in the right direction...*

I want to automate the routine process of compiling custom lists of medical questions by matching a question's attribute tags to the attributes of the patient and ailment. I've built an Access DB which generates lists when queried based on these tags. But I also need to set rules to determine the order the questions are returned in. Otherwise the questions are "out of order" and don't make sense.

Is there a better (and ideally browser based) software or service I could use to achieve such search/reporting functionality? Or does I need to find someone who can add this functionality to my access DB?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how you generate "lists when queried based on these tags".

If you're using sql to select from the database, then it may just be a matter of adding an "order by" to the end of your query:

eg:

```
Select question_no, question from some_table where patient = 'Freddy' 
and tag = 'sick' order by question_no
```

Generally speaking, however you are retrieving these questions; the easiest way of ordering them is by one or more columns in the table you're storing the questions (or a related table)